# How can users access my lightning application without logging in

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps, lightning-community

I created a very simple lightning component in Lightning. component with few fields and submit button I associated that application with my client website. But when was testing it. it is asking login credentials

And my question is I want that application to open for public who ever access it don't need to login just enter data and hit submit that's it. Because they are placing this application url in their website.

Is there any way for this. Please help!. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show your lightning component on a different platform, you have to go with Lightning Out.

Please take a look at this URL to get more information.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out.htm

Hope this help.